# Objective-C Array of Objects

Tags: objective-c, arrays, exc-bad-access

Although experienced with OOP, I am an absolute newbie with Objective-C. I have the following code:

```
// header files have been imported before this statement...
CCSprite *treeObstacle;
NSMutableArray *treeObstacles;

@implementation HelloWorldLayer {
}

-(id) init
{
    // create and initialize our seeker sprite, and add it to this layer
    treeObstacles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];        
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        treeObstacle = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"Icon.png"];
        treeObstacle.position = ccp( 450-i*20, 100+i*20 );
        [self addChild:treeObstacle];
        [treeObstacles addObject: treeObstacle];
    }
    NSLog (@"Number of elements in array = %i", [treeObstacles count]);
    return self;
}

- (void) mymethod:(int)i {
    NSLog (@"Number of elements in array = %i", [treeObstacles count]);
}

@end
```

The first NSLog() statement returns "Number of elements in array = 5". The problem is that (although treeObstacles is a file-scope variable) when calling the method "mymethod", I'll get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

Can anybody please help me?

Thanks a lot
    Christian

Comment: How do you call it?That's important

Comment: @xlc0212's answer is spot on but if you're new to Objective-C, why not start out by building a project with ARC enabled to get you up and running. You can then learn about memory management a bit later on?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually, I was cheating: the name of the method isn't mymethod() but nextFrame() which is being used by the Cocos2D Framework.

The strange thing is, that if I call [self nextFrame:1] somewhere in the init Method, it works as expected...

Comment: Your `-init` method should do `self = [super init]; if (self) { ... }`.  If your immediate superclass is `NSObject`, you can get away without doing so, but it's poor form/habit and may bite you if you later alter your class hierarchy.  (Also, given that you're new to the language, better to stick to the conventional way until you've gained expertise.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you created `treeObstacles` by

```
treeObstacles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
```

which will return an autoreleased object, and you didn't retain it so it will be released soon

you have to retain it by calling `retain` on it

```
[treeObstacles retain];
```

of simple create it by

```
treeObstacles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and you need to remember to release it when done like

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [treeObstacles release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

you need to read more about management in Objective-C
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html

or use ARC so no need to worry retain/release anymore
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

---

another problem, you need to call `[super init]` in your `init` method

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // your initialize code
    }
}
```

otherwise your object won't initialize properly

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help! This is exactly what I was looking for and solves the problem! Thumbs up